# I'd like to add to an array from a do block. How is this done?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is the array, do block and my attempts to write into the new arrays:

`@event_class_array` is dynamic, and does not always have the same arrays, but the format is consistant.

```
@rule_name = Array.new
@rule_count = Array.new
@event_class_array = [["WEB-APPLICATION-ATTACK", 1222], ["MISC-ACTIVITY", 6], ["ATTEMPTED-ADMIN", 6], ["POLICY-VIOLATION", 5]]
@event_class_array.each do |exploit,count| # I also tried .collect with the same results
        @rule_name = [exploit]
        @rule_count = [count]
      end
```

I've also tried this, but it writes out "WEB-APPLICATION-ATTACK" 1222 times, as well as the others:

```
        @rule_name += [exploit]
        @rule_count += [count]
```

same result as:

```
        @rule_name << [exploit]
        @rule_count << [count]
```

I would like for `@rule_name` and `@rule_count` to end up like this:

```
@rule_name = [["WEB-APPLICATION-ATTACK"], ["MISC-ACTIVITY"], ["ATTEMPTED-ADMIN"], ["POLICY-VIOLATION"]]
@rule_count = [[1222], [6], [6], [5]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
@event_class_array = [["WEB-APPLICATION-ATTACK", 1222], ["MISC-ACTIVITY", 6], ["ATTEMPTED-ADMIN", 6], ["POLICY-VIOLATION", 5]]

@rule_name, @rule_count = @event_class_array.transpose
```

Comment: This returns slightly different result that you wanted - you listed you want array of arrays, this will just return array of values. Is this still ok?

Comment: It seems to be working great, I'm passing `@rule_name` and `@rule_count` to Highcharts bar chart and it's displaying the data like I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
@foo = Array.new
@bar = Array.new
```

easy:

```
@foo_bar.each do |x|
  @foo << x[0]
  @bar << x[1]
end
```

to ensure the same index

```
@foo_bar.each_with_index { |x, i|
  @foo[i] = x[0]
  @bar[i] = x[1]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
@rule_name = Array.new
@rule_count = Array.new
@event_class_array.each do |exploit|
  @rule_name << [exploit.first]
  @rule_count << [exploit.last]
end
```

OR

```
@rule_name = Array.new
@rule_count = Array.new
@event_class_array.each do |exploit, count|
  @rule_name << [exploit]
  @rule_count << [count]
end
```

Comment: They both result in the same thing `[["WEB-APPLICATION-ATTACK"], ["WEB-APPLICATION-ATTACK"], ["WEB-APPLICATION-ATTACK"]]` 1222 times. Not `[["WEB-APPLICATION-ATTACK"], ["MISC-ACTIVITY"], ["ATTEMPTED-ADMIN"], ["POLICY-VIOLATION"]]` like I'm looking for.

Comment: I have tried this it's working fine. check rule_name and rule_count